# Set of equidistant points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ under any norm $l_p$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

How can one determine the set of equidistant points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ from two given points, under some norm?

Suppose we have the points $A = (-1,0)$ and $B = (1,0)$, and we want to find the set of equidistant points for some norm $l_p \in [1, \infty)$. I was able to find it computationally, but I am having a lot of trouble to prove it analytically.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Which are you asking about, an arbitrary norm or an $l_p$ norm?

Comment: an $l_p$ norm! Will correct the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the norm is invariant under reflection across the $y$ axis ($(x,y) \to (-x,y)$),  it's obvious that $(0,y)$ is equidistant from $A$ and $B$.

Comment: That I understand, but this is not the entire set... the higher the norm, the wider the set is!

Comment: It is the entire set unless $p=\infty$, because $\|(x,y)\|_p$ is  strictly increasing as a function of $|x|$.

Comment: What should  do in case $p = \infty$?

Comment: $\|(x-1, y)\|_\infty = \max(|x-1|, |y|) = \max(|x+1|,|y|) = \|(x+1,y)\|$ if either $x=0$ or $|y| \ge \max(|x-1|,|x+1|)$.  The points equidistant from $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$  form the union of the $y$ axis and the wedges  $y \ge |x|+1$ and $y \le |x| - 1$.